# Ubuntu is slow on Oracle Virtualbox

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on Oracle Virtualbox 4.2 and when I click on dash home it takes several minutes to open and when it does I try to open software update but it just hangs. What may be the problem? How can i make it more responsive?

Specs:

- Ubuntu 12.04 32bit
- Base Memory 512MB
- Video Memory: 12MB
- Storage: Virtual Size 20GB

Comment: You should add what host you are using. From experience, Virtualbox runs much better on Ubuntu than on Windows, just in case you are using as the host Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your memory is probably not enough; you need to increase it. Also, what are the actual specifications of the computer you are using? If it's an older computer you will experience these problems because the graphics card can't perform fast enough.